# Is storing SQL queries in a database a bad thing?

Tags: sql

We're thinking of storing SQL queries in a separate table. These queries are solely for reporting purposes. Different queries for different reports - moreover the queries would contain placeholders so we can either format or use prepared statements from the Winforms front end (it's a simple 2-tier reporting app) to e.g. format the date range to report on.

I'm having some mixed feelings about that - is it ok to store SQL in a table, that clients will fetch and run?

Comment: Why you don't use stored procedures?

Comment: What type of SQL server are you using

Comment: @Gregoire if you think we should then make an answer - and explain why

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree with Gregoire -- stored procedures are a good way forward, if your language works well with them.

Otherwise, ask:

What's the difference between storing them in source, XML files, SQL etc.? Storage is storage is storage... The potential damage of misuse and implementing without considering the constraints in relation to *your* app is what counts.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion that looks like a quick and dirty solution. What if in the future you wanted to migrate to another DB engine with a different SQL dialect? A better solution is to create a report object model (or xml model) and map it to a corresponding DB schema. This requires more time and effort though.